# GitHub Project not pulling in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to pull a GitHub project into Android Studio and it get struck while proceeding through import project from gradle with default settings and takes infinite time to load.

Comment: Check your internet connection and the size of the project you are downloading. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a re few things to try:

There are several settings you can change in the AndroidStudio repo import function. Try changing the settings on the gradle import.

If you can't get the Android Studio import to work, try using another way to pull your project. You can use the command line or SourceTree. Once you have made a local copy, you can open the project with Android Studio. That has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Done with SourceTree. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that solved your issue. Can you mark this as the answer for future reference?